# How to increase the download speed when downloading HttpURLConnection?

Tags: android, firebase, pdf, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to open a pdf file from firewase without downloading it. It works well and opens a pdf file, but it takes a lot of time. About 30 seconds with a file size of 15mb. The inert speed is good. Here is the code:

```
public class ViewPDFFiles extends AppCompatActivity {
    PDFView pdfView;
    ProgressBar pb;
    SearchView searchView;
    ArrayAdapter kek;
    ListView myPDFListView;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    StorageReference storageReference;
    List<uploadPDF> uploadPDFS;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewallpdf_activity);
        searchView = findViewById(R.id.name_input);
        if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.portrait_only)){
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
        else
        {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }
        int id = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
        EditText searchEditText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(id);
        if (searchEditText != null) {
            searchEditText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        }
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            private boolean activityStartup = true;
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    if (activityStartup) {
                        searchView.clearFocus();
                        activityStartup = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        searchView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                searchView.setIconified(false);
            }
        });
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                kek = (ArrayAdapter) myPDFListView.getAdapter();
                kek.getFilter().filter(s);
                return false;
            }
        });
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ViewPDFFiles.this);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle("Предупреждение!");
        builder.setMessage("Файлы с темами могут открываться некоторое время и отображать пустой белый экран(10-30 секунд), не закрывайте страницу");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Хорошо,я подожду",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        builder.setNegativeButton("", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        myPDFListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.files_list);
        uploadPDFS = new ArrayList<>();

        viewAllFiles();

        myPDFListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                setContentView(R.layout.viewfile_activity);
                if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.portrait_only)){
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                }
                else
                {
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                }
                pdfView=findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
                uploadPDF uploadPDF = uploadPDFS.get(position);
                new RetrievePDFStream().execute(uploadPDF.url);
            }
        });

    }
    class RetrievePDFStream extends AsyncTask<String,Void,InputStream> {
        @Override
        protected InputStream doInBackground(String... strings) {
            InputStream inputStream = null;

            try {
                URL urlx = new URL(strings[0]);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlx.openConnection();
                if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

                }
                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(1000);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return null;
            }
            return inputStream;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(InputStream inputStream) {
            pdfView.fromStream(inputStream)
                    .enableSwipe(true)
                    .load();
        }

    }
    private void viewAllFiles() {
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    uploadPDF uploadPDF = postSnapshot.getValue(com.tokha.diplom.uploadPDF.class);
                    uploadPDFS.add(uploadPDF);
                }
                String[] uploads = new String[uploadPDFS.size()];
                for(int i = 0;i<uploads.length;i++){
                    uploads[i] = uploadPDFS.get(i).getName();
                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, uploads){
                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
                        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                        TextView myText = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                        myText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        return view;
                    }
                };
                myPDFListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
    }

    public void goBack(View view) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

I wanted to try to increase the buffer but I don’t understand how and does it make sense?

Comment: So what's the issue? The time for reading that document?

Comment: yes!The time it takes to download is very time consuming!

Comment: Could you download your pdf with ```curl``` command first? 0.5mb per second is still a decent speed. It is important to confirm speed issue comes on Android platform and doesn't depend on your provider current workload or speed limit on the backend which shares this pdf

Comment: You read from the stream in onPostExecute() where it should be done in doInBackground() to prevent a NetworkOnMainThreadException. Strange you havent one.

Comment: `dialog.show();` You should not have any code after this statement. Put that whole alert at the end of OnCreate().

Comment: I changed it, but it does not solve my problem. I tested the download on different devices. The speed is still very long. I saw what they try to do by increasing the buffer, but I don’t understand this

Comment: Buffer? Which buffer? You have no buffer as that pdfstuff reads directly from the stream.

Comment: Are there options for how to sequentially load data? So that the rest of the pages of the PDF file are loaded during viewing